# c# concurrency - Monitor

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have got this code :

```
if (Monitor.TryEnter(_lock))
{
    try
    {
        ExecuteTask();
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_lock);
    }
}
else
{
    Monitor.Enter(_lock);
    Monitor.Exit(_lock);
}
```

Basically, if one thread is already executing the task the following threads should just wait for it to finish.
Is there a proper solution as opposed to the one I have found doing :

```
    Monitor.Enter(_lock);
    Monitor.Exit(_lock);
```

Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work in the code you've got here?

Comment: It works but I was trying to find a proper solution like Monitor.Wait(_lock) rather than

    Monitor.Enter(_lock);
    Monitor.Exit(_lock);

Answer (score 1):

If there is no need to block the others, you can just use this:

```
if (Monitor.TryEnter(_lock))
{
    try
    {
        ExecuteTask();
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_lock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's not what my code does.
The second thread would be executing the task, when it's not supposed to do it.

Comment: @Dave1980 hm, you do not want the waiting threads to call `ExecuteTask`?

Comment: Basically, if there is a thread which is already executing the "ExecuteTask" there is no point for others to do it. Think of an update stored procedure.
So, the other threads in queue should just wait.

Comment: then your code is just fine, if its ok that the other threads are blocked during the execution. if you don't, just remove the `else` part. I'll update my code.

Comment: It works but I was trying to find a proper solution like Monitor.Wait(_lock) rather than

    Monitor.Enter(_lock);
    Monitor.Exit(_lock);

Comment: Wait will not help you here I think, your code is just fine for your purpose.

Comment: Yeah, wait is for a different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would suggest a solution using `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.PulseAll` with an additional `_executing` flag like

```
Monitor.Enter(_lock);
if (_executing) {   // Another thread is running ExecuteTask()
   Monitor.Wait(_lock);
   Monitor.Exit(_lock);
} else {
  _executing = true;
  Monitor.Exit(_lock);
  try {
    ExecuteTask();
  } finally {
    Monitor.Enter(_lock);
    _executing = false;
    Monitor.PulsaAll(_lock);
    Monitor.Exit(_lock);
  }
}
```

I think this is a bit cleaner: in your solution, holding the lock means "I'm currently updating" as well as "I just waited for another thread to complete the updating". This is not the "original" purpose of a lock (which is to manage exclusive access to some resource).

In my solution, the lock is used to manage exclusive access to the `_executing` flag.

Also note that the original code might have a subtle bug: I suppose that after one thread has finished `ExecuteTask()` the next thread arriving at the code should again perform this operation. No imagine this situation:

- The first thread reaches the code and starts `ExecuteTask()`
- The next thread reaches the code, `TryEnter` fails, the thread goes to the `else` branch and waits for `Monitor.Enter()` to succeed.
- The first thread finishes `ExecuteTask()` and releases the lock
- The second thread `Enter`s the lock in the `else` branch.

and now:

- While the second thread is between `Enter` and `Exit`, a third thread reaches the code. `TryEnter` fails (the second thread holds the lock), the third thread goes to the `else` branch.
- Second thread calls `Exit`, Third Thread calls `Enter`, fourth thread arrives, tries `Enter`, goes to the `else` branch.
- and so on...

So there is a scenario where no further thread ever calls `ExecuteTask()`, all following threads go straight into the else branch.

In your concrete situation this might be improbable or even impossible, but examples like these usually point to design flaws when it comes to parallel programming.

Comment: Sorry, but I think that in your solution the second thread would never get to the point :

    if (_executing)   // Another thread is running ExecuteTask()
        Monitor.Wait(_lock);

as it would wait on Monitor.Enter(_lock);

Comment: @Dave1980 You're right, of course... I fixed the code, and hope I got it right this time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time each blocked thread waits using an argument to TryEnter

```
if (Monitor.TryEnter(_lock,TIMEOUT))//try to acquire lock for TIMEOUT miliseconds
{
    try
    {
       //something
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_lock);
    }
}
else//lock was not acquired
{
     //Handle TIMEOUT error
}
```